# “adapt the discussion to suit your own needs” <- correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, nouns

Consider this:

> The theory above was put forward in the most general way possible. You
>   should adapt the discussion to suit your own needs.

Is the phrase “you should adapt the discussion to suit your own needs” correct? I don’t find it on Google, which is usually a sign of trouble.

If it’s wrong, why is it wrong, and what are some alternatives?

Comment: Try googling your last sentence. Do you think it is "correct"?

Comment: I could not find a complete match for the following sentence in google too, "When you go downstairs to look into the freezer, you might find a scrap of pizza or two." Could my sentence be improper? Or, even wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find the phrase on Google because it's a long sentence, and most sentences above a certain length threshold are unique. This is a natural consequence of the number of possible ways there are to make a sentence.

In any case, your phrase is perfectly grammatical and clear. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

That's a fairly lengthy phrase to try to find. I think you are really just asking about the *adapt to suit your own needs* part.  In this case, there is nothing wrong with the phrase.  You could even leave out *own* and say simply

> You should adapt the discussion to suit your needs.

*your own needs* is a bit redundant, but not at all ungrammatical.